# If I wear two Plunderer's Ring, does the effect stack?

Tags: bloodstained-ritual-of-the-night

The Plunderer's Ring descriptions is

> A ring that increases the rate of item drops / DEF 1, LCK 5.

I found a second Plunderer's Ring and I can see that the defense and luck stats go up if I equip both.

Is the rate drop effect the same as if I equipped only one, or does it increase for each ring?

Comment: I don't know if it stacks but the Plunderer's rings does indeed help with drops. I went for an all out luck build and had a pair of Gambler's rings. I found less items when grinding away for sure.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](https://steamcommunity.com/app/692850/discussions/0/1638662230385354114/) discussion:

> LCK = chance to find items and chance to land critical strikes
>
> LCK might also affect Shard drops.
>
> I think luck has 2 functions with it. 
>   1. Definitely effects drop rate of rare items such as Armor and Weapons.
>   2 I think it has to do with critical strikes

And when someone asked for the best weapon drop build in [this](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/158368-bloodstained-ritual-of-the-night/77804549) discussion the kit suggested had two plunderer's rings

> Best armor set for LCK:
>   Ribbon
>   Kalasiris
>   Plunder ring
>   Plunder ring
>   Bunny scarf
>   Augment Luck yellow shard maxed
>   Augment Luck white shard
>   Eat all foods that give luck

Both of these discussions are from the bloodstained community and not actual an official statement, but I think it's safe to assume that when you see your LCK increase with each ring then drop rates are also stacking, because that is what LCK represents.